# Remove duplicates in partition while maintaining order of row number

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table as shown below with multiple entries and duplicate ID/SUBIDs.

```
Id  subid   Rownum
1   A   1
1   A   2
2   A   1
2   B   2
2   A   3
3   C   1
3   C   2
3   D   3
3   D   4
3   C   5
3   A   6
```

The above table is partitioned by ID and the row number is based on the subids for each partition.

I want to create a new table where there are no duplicate ID/SUBID combination in any partition while also maintaining the order of the subids.

Output

```
Id  subid   Rownum
1   A   1
2   A   1
2   B   2
3   C   1
3   D   2
3   A   3
```

Can you please help me with this. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select id, subid,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by min(rownum)) as new_rownum
from t
group by id, subid
order by id, min(rownum);
```

This is an aggregation query that uses `min(rownum)` to maintain the ordering that you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=346514f16a8c50d13a344031b5664854) is a db<>fiddle (which happens to use Postgres, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. first use `distinct` to get Id and subId and then use a window function `row_number`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZSWE4sQwb61jfMibDzNrG/0).

```
select
    Id,
    subid,
    row_number() over (partition by Id order by subid) as rowNum
from
(
    select
      distinct Id,
      subid
   from myTable
 ) t
```

output:

```
| Id  | subid | rowNum  |
| --- | ----- | ------- |
| 1   | A     | 1       |
| 2   | A     | 1       |
| 2   | B     | 2       |
| 3   | A     | 1       |
| 3   | C     | 2       |
| 3   | D     | 3       |
```

Comment: Thank you. But will the inner distinct subquery guarantee that the order of the subids dont change?

Comment: Hi. No this does not work as expected. The order of the subids is not getting maintained here. ID = 3 should have the subids as C, D, A in that order if you look at the input.